# What does setting the automatic_scaling max_idle_instances to zero (0) do?

Tags: google-app-engine, autoscaling, cost-management

What does setting the automatic_scaling max_idle_instances to zero (0) do?

```
automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 0
  min_idle_instances: 0
```

Does it cause an active instance to shutdown immediately once it has finished processing it's current requests?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can't even set `max_idle_instances` it to `0`, you'll see this error at deployment time:

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
automatic_scaling.max_idle_instances (0), must be in the range [1,1000].
--- end server output ---
```

Deploying a version with a lower number than the one already deployed *might* not (immediately) shut down idle instances already running that exceed the newly configured number - the limit is not a "hard" one, in some cases it can be exceeded. For example, from the `automatic_scaling` row in the [Scaling elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements) table:

> **Note:** When settling back to normal levels after a load spike, the number of idle instances can temporarily exceed your specified
>   maximum. However, you will not be charged for more instances than the
>   maximum number you've specified.

You should also keep in mind that this config applies to the **idle** instances, not to the **dynamic/active** instances (which are the ones handling most of the traffic). Lowering the `max_idle_instances` config won't affect the dynamic instances.

The idle instances only serve transient overflowing traffic - requests that the currently running dynamic instances can't handle with acceptable latency during sudden rises of the incoming traffic, while GAE spins up additional dynamic instances.

From the same doc referenced above:

> Because App Engine keeps idle instances in reserve, it is unlikely
>   that requests will enter the pending queue except in exceptionally
>   high load spikes. You will need to test your application and expected
>   traffic volume to determine the ideal number of instances to keep in
>   reserve.

Comment: This explanation is helpful, thanks. As a note though, I've got a service deployed with a value of zero, without error. So it seems it's possible to set a value of zero. e.g. https://github.com/leighmcculloch/looks.wtf/blob/8d80dc32a4ee8b02d1c529a8c009a1247ac54b19/services/slackcommandlook/app.yaml#L6

Comment: OK, I should have been more specific - the error I got was for a standard env python app deployed with `appcfg.py`, not with `gcloud`. I guess SDKs may differ a bit.